# django-oauth2-provider

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

Does any one used django-oauth2-provider as django oauth2 solution?

I've clone django-oauth2-provider code from github https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider, and run the example site provided.

But I don't know how to test it.
When I type this in my browser:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2/authorize/2/?client_id=fc79b3fd7e65b904836b`

I got

```
unauthorized_client An unauthorized client tried to access your resources.
```

It seems that my client_id had failed passed to the site?

Comment: Why do not you see [fixture data](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider/blob/master/provider/oauth2/fixtures/test_oauth2.json#L5)?

Comment: I create a client in the admin site myself, and the client_id is from admin site. I'm sure the client_id is exist in the database, but I just don't know why it response that.  @Marazmiki

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the wrong URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2/authorize/?client_id=fc79b3fd7e65b904836b&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_TARGET>&response_type=code&status=abc
```

Then the app redirects you to

```
/oauth2/authorize/2/
```

by either issuing an HTTP200 upon success or HTTP400 upon failure.